# Iterating through sub-directories with PHP

Tags: php

Beginner PHP coder.  I've written this piece of code to iterate through a directory and capture some data then use that data to update a db.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "popcorn";
$password = "**********";
$dbname = "professional_test123";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$path = "/home/professional/www/dan/myFiles";
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;

$title = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$size = filesize($file);
$myFile[$title]['size'] = filesize($file);

$sql = "UPDATE Files SET Size = '$size' WHERE Name = '$title'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

}
closedir($handle);
$conn->close();
```

What I want to do now is iterate through the root directories many sub-directories and collect the same data from all of them.  I read that I can use RecursiveDirectoryIterator in conjunction with RecursiveIteratorIterator to accomplish this but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my code.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: "In order to understand recursion you must first understand recursion". You can use RecursiveDirectoryIterator with RecursiveIteratorIterator or you can wrap your code in to recursive function.

Comment: Is my answer working for you?

Comment: @IarsAnders Yes, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start - a recursive function that calls itself if it encounters a folder, or runs your db query if it encounters a file. $myFile is passed in by reference so the function is allowed to add new items to it on the fly, without needing to return a value out of the function.

```
$myFile = array();
$path = "/home/professional/www/dan/myFiles";
updateSize($path, $myFile);

function updateSize($path, &$myFile){
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ('.' === $file) continue;
            if ('..' === $file) continue;

            $full_path = $path.'/'.$file;

            if(is_dir($full_path)){
                //function calls itself
                updateSize($full_path, $myFile); 
            } else {
                $title = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);                
                $size = filesize($full_path);
                $myFile[$title]['size'] = $size;

                $sql = "UPDATE Files SET Size = '$size' WHERE Name = '$title'";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
        }//while
    closedir($handle);
    }//if
}
```

Comment: I went with your method of if (is_dir($full_path)).  I had to change a couple other things but it works now, thanks!